# Output the alphabet using the alphabet

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

The title is pretty self-explanatory, isn't it?

Your task is to output the alphabet (the string `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`) to STDOUT, using each and every letter of the alphabet in your program once and only once.

Oh, and for a bit of extra fun?

The letters "g", "o", "l" and "f" must be in order (just for the code to be a bit more code-y).

Rules:

- Only standard letters of the alphabet from ASCII count as letters (`ë != e`).
- Both uppercase and lowercase characters count as letters (if you have `E`, you are not allowed to have `e`).
- You are allowed to use comments, but every character in the comment is equal to 2 bytes.
- Your final score will be the byte-count of your program, subtracted by 26.

This is `code-golf`, so shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: May I take any input?

Comment: @KennyLau Why would you want to take input? But, yes if you want.

Comment: I didn't think the question through, did I?

Comment: I downvoted because it is too straight-forward.

Comment: Dammit, can I delete the question? I might want some revisions of it in the sandbox.

Comment: Well, it is interesting in languages like Python, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40088/discussion-between-derpfacepython-and-kenny-lau).

Comment: Why the arbitrary "one answer per person" rule?

Comment: I see that this question has some rather arbitrary rules and the community in general seems to punish that, but I think this challenge might have some interesting optimizations in some languages. And I don't think it deserves quite the negative score that it has

Comment: @Doorknob That was because LeakyNun had 5 answers, and it was kinda cluttery.

Comment: @DerpfacePython If someone is posting a lot of answers, the reaction should be "this challenge is too trivial" rather than "I need to forbid multiple answers"

Comment: @Mego Ah, I understand. So should I delete the question and move on? Or should I leave it?

Comment: Since it has answers, you cannot delete it. Your best bet would be to remove the "one answer per person" rule and move on.

Comment: If I revise this question and repost it, it'll still be unpopular, right?

Comment: @DerpfacePython It's unethical to repost here. It will be most probably ***mod-deleted***.

Comment: @LeakyNun I upvoted the question because it is quite interesting to solve in [dc](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80311/output-the-alphabet-using-the-alphabet/91477#91477) as well.

Comment: This was a fun challenge in SmileBASIC.

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>27</s> 26 - 26 = 0 bytes

Thanks to [Katenkyo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41019/katenkyo) for saving 1 byte :). Code:

```
golfAqbcdehijkmnprstuvwxyz
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=Z29sZkFxYmNkZWhpamttbnByc3R1dnd4eXo&input=).

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandHamDJ The `golf` part is just a bunch of no-ops. The `A` pushes the lowercase alphabet and the `q` after that quits the program, which then implicitly prints the lowercase alphabet.

Comment: "Both uppercase and lowercase characters count as letters (if you have E, you are not allowed to have e)." so you can technically use `golfAqbcdehijkmnprstuvwxyz` which scores 0 :)

Comment: @Katenkyo Thanks :), updated.

Comment: Faster code (from what I've read): `Aqgolfbcdehijkmnprstuvwxyz`

Answer (score 5):

## Brainfuck, 67 - 26 + 26 (comment) = <s>41</s> 67 bytes

```
golfabcdehijkmnpqrstuvwxyz++++++++[>++++++++++++>+++<<-]>>++[-<+.>]
```

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=Z29sZmFiY2RlaGlqa21ucHFyc3R1dnd4eXorKysrKysrK1s-KysrKysrKysrKysrPisrKzw8LV0-PisrWy08Ky4-XQ&input=)

Comment: I think that the `golfabcdehijkmnpqrstuvwxyz` part is a comment!

Comment: There's a slight difference between a no-op and a comment...

Comment: `+-` or `<>` would be a no-op. Characters not in the brainfuck alphabet are comments.

Comment: Actually, you would need to add 52 bytes to your score, as each comment character counts twice.

Comment: Count twice, and then minus 26, which is the same as what we have now.

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 36  + 13 + 9 - 26 = 32 bytes

```
:g
@echo ab%0pqrstuvwxyz
:lfdijkmn
```

Requires that the batch file itself be named `cdefghijklmno`. Scored as 36 (size of file `cdefghijklmno`) + 13 (size of filename `cdefghijklmno`) + 9 (commented letters) - 26.

Edit: Saved 29 bytes even under my scoring scheme thanks to @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος.

Comment: If I do not miscomprehend, your task is to output "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" to STDOUT.

Comment: @KennyLau Sorry I misunderstood the question. Let me think about it.

Comment: Read the rules again, please. You will delete this answer out of shame.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I'll be in good company!

Comment: They're not comments, they're labels, so I think you don't have to count comment characters.

Comment: There are no rules about the file being named `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. So your score is 10. Also, if you use the code [here](//pastebin.com/3t7JDgRe), your score is 8, and you have to name your file `cdefghijklmno`. It's a win/win situation.

Comment: Actually, you must count every commented byte *twice*, so you add +18 instead of +9, and still save 20 bytes.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ But I already counted them once as part of the original 36 byte size of the file `cdefghijklmno`.

Comment: @Neil Good... ...morning?

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ I'm awake, so it can't be morning!

Comment: @Neil I just said a good evening, since it's evening...

Answer (score 3):

## Jolf, 27 - 26 = 1 byte

```
goΔaplfbcdehijkmnqrstuvwxyz
```

`o` assigns `Δ` to `apl`, which `a`lerts `pl`, which is the lowercase alphabet. I take it that "in order" does not mean "adjacent to". You can see that `f` follows `l` which follows `o` which follows `g`. [Try it out here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=Z2_OlGFwbGZiY2RlaGlqa21ucXJzdHV2d3h5eg)

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 29 - 26 = 3 bytes

```
"golfabcdehijkmnpqrstuvwxyz"$
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=ImdvbGZhYmNkZWhpamttbnBxcnN0dXZ3eHl6IiQ&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyke, 29 - 26 = 3 bytes

```
"golfabcdehijkmnpqrstuvwxyz"S
```

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, 29-26 = 3 bytes

```
'abcdehijkmnpqrstuvwxyzgolf'S
```

[Try it Online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=J2FiY2RlaGlqa21ucHFyc3R1dnd4eXpnb2xmJ1M&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## J, 36 - 26 = 10 bytes

```
'golfabcdehjkmnpqrstvwxyz']u:97+i.26
```

Not a comment, just a string that's discarded. `u:` converts numbers to ASCII chars, and `97+i.26` is a range from 0..25 with vectorized addition over 97, the char code of `a`. Here's an alternative (albeit longer) solution using `a.`:

```
'golfbcdehjkmnpqrstvwxyz']a.{~97+i.26
```

Answer (score 2):

### dc, 111 - 26 = 85 bytes

```dc
[gol][P]s@[abcdef]1 1=@103 1 1=@[hijk]1 1=@108 1 1=@[mn]1 1=@111
1 1=@112 1 1=@[qr]1 1=@115 1 1=@[tuvwxyz]1 1=@
```

**Run:** dc -f alphabet_letters.dc

**Output:**

```sh
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

I use `1 1=@` as a trick to simulate `l@x`, that executes the print command `P` stored in register `@`. This is one example of a language that entailed a non-trivial solution for this task.

Comment: The output is supposed to be the alphabet in, er, alphabetical order.

Comment: @Jordan I wasn't sure, because the statement said that the `g`, `o`, `l` and `f` letters must be in order so I thought the rest could be in any order. I'll correct my entry.

Comment: I believe OP intends for the output to be `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, and for the `g`, `o` `l`, and `f` letters to be in that order in the source code, not the output.

Comment: @Jordan thanks for clarifying things up for me. My updated answer should be correct now.

Answer (score 1):

## Jelly, 29 - 26 = 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“golfabcdehijkmnpqrstuvwxyz”Ṣ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcZ29sZmFiY2RlaGlqa21ucHFyc3R1dnd4eXrigJ3huaI&input=)

Comment: Dammit, Kenny... all the good solutions, gone like that.

Comment: What encoding are you using? I see some non-ascii characters.

Comment: Updated, thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1):

## Actually, 29 - 26 = 3 bytes

```
"golfabcdehijkmnpqrstuvwxyz"S
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=ImdvbGZhYmNkZWhpamttbnBxcnN0dXZ3eHl6IlM&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>57</s> <s>37</s> 47 - 26 = 21 bytes

I'm ashamed it took me that many tries to arrive at this super obvious solution.

```
"gol";$><<"abcdef\147hijk\154mnp\157qrstuvwxyz"
```

See it on ideone: http://ideone.com/FAtiy3

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, <s>68</s> 61 bytes -26 = 35

```
_=97@V?CHR$(_);
_=_+1GOSUB"@"+KEY(3)[2]*(_<123)@ADLIJFMNPQTWXZ
```

Explained:

```
_=97 'set variable _ to 97 (ascii value of "a")
@V 'label
 ?CHR$(_) 'convert _ to a character and print
 _=_+1 'add 1 to _
GOSUB"@"+KEY(3)[2]*(_<123) 'jump to @V (KEY(3) is "SAVE") if _ is less than 123 (ascii code for z +1)
@ADLIJFMNPQTWXZ 'create a label with the unused letters
```